# Laravel Restful API

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I have a problem when my SQL on postgresSQL will be implement to Laravel

The query is

```
SELECT
    ID AS id_bpr,
    0 AS bpr_cabang,
    bpr
FROM
    m_bpr
WHERE
    ID != 0
```

The query has been succesfull proced on Navicat, but when i try to implement in Laravel that query not working. This is code in laravel.

```
$allBpr = DB::table('m_bpr')
                    ->select('id as id_bpr',
                            '0 as bpr_cabang',
                            'bpr')
                    ->where('id', '!=', 0)
                    ->get();
```

Why i implement that query to laravel?

Comment: What exactly is the error you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel will try to parse all fields in the `SELECT` part of your query. Because `0` is not a valid column, this will fail.

Wrap the option in `\DB::raw()` to tell Laravel to not parse the string.

```
$allBpr = DB::table('m_bpr')
    ->select(
        'id as id_bpr',
        \DB::raw('0 as bpr_cabang'),
        'bpr'
    )
    ->where('id', '!=', 0)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Glad I could help, consider marking this as the answer so other users might find this as well.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing wrong parameter. pass `ID` like in above query instead of `id`

```
->where('ID', '!=', 0)
```